# how to make ps1 display full path name

Tags: bashrc, ps1

using ubuntu 12.04.3,
i've modified my PS1 to [\u@\h ]\w$ which SHOULD display as follows:

```
[user@host /home/user]$
```

but it doesn't
it's still

```
[user@host ~]$
```

this used to work.
what changed?

Answer (score 3):

Replace the "\w" with "\$PWD"

```
[\u@\h ]\$PWD$
```

See also https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizingBashPrompt

Comment: You should not escape the dollar sign if you use single quotes: `PS1='[\u@\h $PWD]\$ '`